# Determine (root), (root+1), (root+2) in hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, recursive-query

I've got hierarchical data in Oracle. Each Row has an `id`, `parent_id` and `name`.

For each row I want to get

- the root ID (this is straightforward using `connect_by_root`)
- the ID of the node one level above root
- the ID of the node two levels above root

My baseline is

```
SELECT
    id,
    parent_id,
    name,
    connect_by_root id root,
    <child_of_root_in_this_exact_path> child1_id,
    <child_of_the_child_above> child2_id,
FROM table
    START WITH id = 1
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
```

The parent and grandparent of the child would be trivial (wouldn't need a hierachical query at all for this), but how do I find specific nodes from the opposite direction?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not entirely clear what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, given any ID, you want to find it, all its children, and all its grandchildren. You didn't quite show how you plan to distinguish them in the output; here is one way:

```
select  id, case level when 1 then 'Self' 
                       when 2 then 'Child' 
                       when 3 then 'Grandchild' end as generation
from    table
start   with id = 1
connect by id = prior parent_id
where   level <= 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
WITH roots ( id, parent_id, name, root_id, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         parent_id,
         name,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ),
         LEVEL
  FROM   table_name
  START WITH
         id = 1
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR id = parent_id
)
SELECT id,
       parent_id,
       name,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( root_id ) AS root,
       CASE lvl
       WHEN 1 THEN NULL
       WHEN 2 THEN id
       ELSE CONNECT_BY_ROOT( parent_id )
       END AS child1_id,
       CASE
       WHEN lvl >= 3
       THEN CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id )
       END AS child2_id
FROM   roots
START WITH
       lvl <= 3
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR lvl >= 3
AND    PRIOR id = parent_id
```

Which, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, parent_id, name ) AS
SELECT LEVEL,
       CASE WHEN LEVEL > 1 THEN LEVEL - 1 END,
       'name' || LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | PARENT_ID | NAME  | ROOT | CHILD1_ID | CHILD2_ID
> -: | --------: | :---- | ---: | --------: | --------:
>  2 |         1 | name2 |    1 |         2 |      null
>  3 |         2 | name3 |    1 |         2 |         3
>  4 |         3 | name4 |    1 |         2 |         3
>  5 |         4 | name5 |    1 |         2 |         3
>  6 |         5 | name6 |    1 |         2 |         3
>  1 |      null | name1 |    1 |      null |      null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4afeb582d6893d8fd7f50339cad39215)*